# Can one field in settings be dependent of two other in xml?

Tags: android, xml, dependencies, application-settings

Is there a way to make field "A" dependent of two fields "key1" and "key2"? I'm using a list of values and there are 2 options to use them and I need either one of them to "unlock" it without having to duplicate field "A". Something like this `android:dependency="key1 | key2"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `android:dependency="key1 | key2` your app will crash. I dont know if there is a way to do it in xml, but you can do that in code like this:

```
final ListPreference fieldA = (ListPreference) findPreference("fieldA");
SwitchPreference key1 = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("key1");
SwitchPreference key2 = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("key2");
key1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue){
        fieldA.setEnabled((Boolean) newValue);
        return true;
    }
});
key2.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue){
        fieldA.setEnabled((Boolean) newValue);
        return true;
    }
});
```